# Getting DatePicker value in new Activity

Tags: android

Hi and thanks for looking at this newbi question.

I have looked for anykind of answer that is relevent to my problem and cant seem to find the problem that Im having or maybe I need someone to explain what Im doing wrong.

Anyway my problem is that I am trying to learn Intents and passing data between activities putExtra, getExtra and so on.., so I have created a very simple app with its function to just pass the selected date from a date picker into the new activity and display it on the screen.
I must be doing something wrong as I get a "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException" when I click the button to start the next activity I have tried different code from other answered questions but to no avail, Is there something im missing?.
My code is below and thankyou for a second time to all of you for any answers.

first activity

```
package date.Picker;




import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;   


public class DatePickerActivity extends Activity  {           

 int year;  
 int month;  
 int day; 

Button selectButton;
DatePicker datePicker;


@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                   

    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           

public void onClick(View v){         

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),        datePickerResult.class);

    month = datePicker.getMonth();  
    day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth(); 
    year = datePicker.getYear();


    intent.putExtra("year",year);  
    intent.putExtra("month",month);  
    intent.putExtra("day",day);  

    startActivity(intent);


    } 

    });
}
 }
```

second activity

```
package date.Picker;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class datePickerResult extends Activity {

 int year;  
 int month;  
 int day; 

 TextView textView1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dpresult);

textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  

    extras.getBundle("year"); 
    extras.getBundle("day");  
    extras.getBundle("month");  


    textView1.setText(year);
 }
}
```

So thankyou for any answers or help that you have. Sorry if its a bit of a time waster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that pops out is that you have called:

```
textView1.setText(year);
```

The compiler sees the `int year` as a resource ID, so it tries to find a resource with that as an ID. Since it can't, it gives up. Try one of the following two lines instead:

```
textView1.setText(year+"");
textView1.setText(Integer.valueOf(year));
```

Next, you're not assigning the return values of the following:

```
extras.getBundle("year"); 
extras.getBundle("day");  
extras.getBundle("month");
```

What you need to do is pick the extra, and assign it to a variable. Like so:

```
year = extras.getInt("year");
day = extras.getInt("day");
month = extras.getInt("month");
```

That should correctly get the year/day/month values from your `Bundle`'s `Intent`.

Comment: Hi Soxxeh, Thanks alot for your answer it has solved the problem and iv accepted it accordingly. Once again thanks for your time and effort as it was a good answer.